# index 1 out of range for positional args tuple

Tags: python, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I'm trying to print the following line, which is part of an auxiliary classifier GAN code:

```
print('{0:<22s} | {1:15s} | {2:15s} | {3:5s}'.format('component', *discriminator.metrics_names))
```

but it results in this error:

> IndexError: Replacement index 1 out of range for positional args tuple

Comment: maybe first use `print( discriminator.metrics_names )` or `print( *discriminator.metrics_names )` to see what you have in variable. It seems you have less values then you need in string formatting.

Comment: I agree with @furas. Check discriminator.metrics_names. Based on your print statement it should have 3 values atleast. If < 3 then print will fail.

Comment: @furas is on the right track, but I'd try `len(discriminator.metrics_names)`.   That has to give you a result of 4 or higher for you to not get this error message

Comment: @furas but they are actually the same number of values. I took the code from this link [mnist_acgan](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_acgan.py)

Comment: maybe `discriminator.metrics_names` in original code (in your link) works correctly but in your code gives different result. We can't help without minimal working code which gives this error.